Exception ->"main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
Even though the program is correct - still I'm not getting the output due to below error
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.8.0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at org.testng.log4testng.Logger.lambda$getLogger$0(Logger.java:30)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1708)
    at org.testng.log4testng.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:30)
    at org.testng.TestNG.<clinit>(TestNG.java:113)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNGFactory7_8.createRemoteTestNG(RemoteTestNGFactory7_8.java:16)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:67)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 6 more

Tried to add all the external jars and added dependencies still same issue persist

Could you include your Log4J.properties file into the question text? It would also be interesting to know your operating system, the value of the CLASSPATH environment variable, and whether the expected classes are in that path.
